# Подскажите библиотеку, для для работы с ком портами "малинки" через си

Tags: c, arduino, raspberry-pi

В проекте потребовалось управлять ардуинкой подключенной к малинке по usb. Мне нужно сделать это с помощью си, на крайняк с++. Порылся в сети, не могу найти нормального инструмента для этого, подскажите пожалуйста простую и легкую библиотеку для этого.

Comment: Ничего не понял, откуда вдруг взялось USB, когда в заголовке *ком*? (да и неплохо было бы, если бы вы писали более внятно по-русски или по-английски соответствующие термины)

Comment: `open("/dev/serial0", ...` и `tcgetattr` + `tcsetattr`

Comment: @PavelGridin, т.е я могу писать данные в ком порт с помощью системных вызовов предоставляемых unix? Открываю файл по имени ком порта?

Comment: @DenverToha, да, подразумевая, что на малине linux bkb другой *nix, а не какой-нить RISCOS или ещё что-то более изощрённое... ардуинка будет где-то в районе `/dev/ttyUSB0`. не забудь проверить права, если запускаешь от пользователя...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, как я понял, большинство устройство ввода/вывода и не только в unix воспринимает как файлы. Возможно ли с помощью функции open + read читать видеопоток с веб камеры? ПРосто хотел бы избежать использования opencv. Извиняюсь, что не по теме, просто пришла такая мысль

Comment: @DenverToha, да, интерфейсы будут в `/dev/videoN`, если интересно, то гоглить в сторону `v4l2` (*video for linux*)... только кроме `open`+`read` ещё пригодится `ioctl`... но для адекватной работы со всем этим я бы советовал всё же использовать `libv4l` — это стандартная библиотека, по сути это обёртка над системными вызовами + прозрачный конвертер форматов на случай если камера возвращает только весьма стрёмные варианты оных... `opencv` работает с камерами через неё же, если что...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, спасибо